# UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingImage calling custom function upon completion

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working on an app with a MapView, I have a custom button that is displayed on top of the MapView. When the user clicks on that button, I would like to launch the camera where the user then takes a picture and selects "Use Photo". I have all of this working, except for the next part.. once the user selects "Use Photo", I would like the image that was captured to be passed to another function. Then the view is released and it goes back to the map.. I was thinking this could be accomplished using the completion handler? but I'm not quite crystal clear on if this would be the best approach and if so, how to pass the image of type UIImage to the function to be processed. Can anyone help?

I have something like the following right now:

```
@IBAction func mapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
     let image = UIImagePickerController()
     //image.delegate = self
     image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
     image.allowsEditing = false
     self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: customFunction(image))
}

func customFunction(image: UIImage) {
     print("Do Something with Image")
}
```

Comment: Why setting delegate is commented? Uncomment `image.delegate = self`

Comment: I forgot to include UINavigationControllerDelegate in my ViewController definition so it was giving me an error. I fixed it and utilized a a little bit of what @rmaddy said below to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the image picker delegate by uncommenting the line `//image.delegate = self` (for clarity you might want to rename the picker to imagePicker or imagePickerController to make it clear this is a picker and not the image that is picked).

Also `didFinishPickingImage` is deprecated so it would be better to use `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

To call the function on the completion handler :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {        
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { self.customFunction(pickedImage)} )   
        }else{
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you can just call the function and them dismiss the picker:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {        
     if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
          customFunction(pickedImage)   
     }
     dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image returned in the delegate can be saved first in a reference. Then dismiss the view controller, then call your custom method. This will make sure that the image reference is saved before dismissing the view controller.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
     let selectedImage=image;
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
     customFunction(image);
}
```